# Nokogiri Exclude HTML Class

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape the names of all the people who commented on a post in our Facebook group. I downloaded the file locally and am able to scrape the names of the people who commented plus the people who replied to those comments. I only want the original comments, not the replies... it seems like I have to exclude the UFIReplyList class but my code is still pulling all the names. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pry'

class Scraper
  @@all = []

  def get_page
    file = File.read('/Users/mark/Desktop/raffle.html')
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(file)
    # binding.pry

    doc.css(".UFICommentContent").each do |post|
      # binding.pry
      author = post.css(".UFICommentActorName").css(":not(.UFIReplyList)").text

      @@all << author
    end

    puts @@all
  end
end

Scraper.new.get_page
```

Comment: Can you post a small example block of HTML for one of these comments?

Comment: sure, Facebook has a lot of code, but this is the smallest sample I could get...  i had to put it on Google Drive since it was too long
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1djxVelyd_9PAgPGJ4SwNCVQzp4gsEme3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Try again with a small bit of html and desired output.

Comment: sorry, I'll try to explain better... for a post in Facebook, we have about 300 comments, I only want to get the individuals who actually posted each comment https://drive.google.com/file/d/14-69HNnUUchiKLQMoBehuxjQDc0v94T2/view?usp=sharing but with my current code I'm also getting people who also replied to the original comments https://drive.google.com/file/d/1opVpSW1paH0burIPjpsHKQgUi_0SgWEx/view?usp=sharing 
Say Person A commented and then Person B and Person C replied to that comment. I only want the name of Person A but am currently also getting B and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse ancestors for every `.UFICommentActorName` element, to reject those contained within a `.UFIReplyList` element.

```
@authors_nodes = doc.css(".UFICommentActorName").reject do |node|

  # extract all ancestor class names; 
  # beware of random whitespace and multiple classes per node
  class_names = node.ancestors.map{ |a| a.attributes['class'].value rescue nil }
  class_names = class_names.compact.map{ |names| names.split(' ') }
  class_names = class_names.flatten.map(&:strip)

  # reject if .UFIReplyList found
  class_names.include?('UFIReplyList')

end

@authors_nodes.map(&:text)
```

Comment: thank you so much! that worked perfectly and I mostly understand it!